# DB2 function timing out with a deadlock or timeout error in query

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have created the following DB2 function below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CLAIMS.get_gross_amount
(payment_option varchar(30),fy date, released date, grossamt int, taxamt int)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
BEGIN
  declare gross_amt int;
  declare tax_amt int;
  
   IF (payment_option = 'overpayment') 
   THEN
     if (fy = '2021' AND released <= '2020-06-30') then
           SET gross_amt = grossamt;
     elseif (fy = '2021' and (released >= '2020-07-01' and released <= '2021-06-30'))
     then
           SET gross_amt = grossamt - taxamt;
           SET tax_amt = taxamt - 100;
     end if;
   ELSEIF (payment_option = 'underpayment' OR payment_option = 'backpayment')
   THEN
      if (fy = '2021' and (released >= '2020-07-01' and released <= '2021-06-30')) 
      then
          SET gross_amt = grossamt - taxamt;
          SET tax_amt = taxamt - 100;
       end if;
    ELSE
         SET gross_amt = grossamt;
   END IF;   
         
   RETURN gross_amt;
END
```

When I invoke this as follows:

```
select claims.get_gross_amount('overpayment','2021','2020-06-30',1000,100) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

I am getting the below error:

```
17:24:07  FAILED  [SELECT - 0 rows, 300.297 secs]  [Code: -911, SQL State: 40001]  The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "68".. SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, DRIVER=4.22.29  
select claims.get_gross_amount('overpayment','2021','2020-06-30',1000,100) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Any reason why a deadlock should occur?.

Thanks
R

Comment: What exact Db2 version and what is in the diagnostic log file?

Comment: Why is it declared as "CONTAINS SQL"? I don't see any SQL SELECT / UPDATE / ...

Comment: First of all your function is incorrectly coded. It throws incorrect string representation of date error on `fy (date) = '2021' (varchar)` - `2021` is not valid date. Change the `fy` data type to `varchar (4)` (or `int` with appropriate changes to the function body and actual `fy` parameter value upon invocation).

Comment: Secondly, `rc=68` is not deadlock, it's lock timeout, and it's really strange that you get it. To understand the reason of this you may do the following. In your calling session: use `SET CURRENT LOCK TIMEOUT = 120` (2 mins of waiting on lock max) and remember the output of `values mon_get_application_handle`. Use "SELECT * [SYSIBM.MON_LOCKWAITS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=mv-mon-lockwaits-retrieve-metrics-applications-that-are-waiting-obtain-locks) WHERE REQ_APPLICATION_HANDLE = remembered_handle" to get the information on the lock wait event in another session.

Comment: @data_henrik `CONTAINS SQL` is a minimum access level allowed in the [CREATE FUNCTION (SQL scalar, table, or row) statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-function-sql-scalar-table-row). SELECTs would require `READS SQL DATA` and UPDATEs - `MODIFIES SQL DATA`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to compile the function successfully. But when I call it as: select claims.get_gross_amount('overpayment','2021','2020-06-30',1000,100) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;  Getting the below error: [Code: -911, SQL State: 40001]  The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "68".. SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, DRIVER=4.22.29

Comment: It's compiled and executed successfully on my database. What's the client you use? Do you have autocommit turned on?

Answer (score 0):

If you can repeat this over and over there might be a transaction open which have acquired locks on one of the rows you are accessing. You can check for long running transactions as:

```
select
    x.agent_id,
    substr(z.corr_TOKEN,1,12) as ip,
    cast(y.stmt_text as varchar(800)) as stmt,
    x.locks_held,
    x.APPL_IDLE_TIME,
    x.UOW_START_TIME
from sysibmadm.SNAPAPPL x
join sysibmadm.snapstmt y
    on x.agent_id = y.agent_id
join sysibmadm.SNAPAPPL_INFO z
    on x.agent_id = z.agent_id
where UOW_STOP_TIME is null
  and TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(current_timestamp - UOW_START_TIME)) > 1
order by UOW_START_TIME
;
```